# About the transformation of a formula (of probability products)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I am reading a paper and getting stuck with some involved formula transformations. Here comes the settings of the problem corresponding to the formula:

*Initially*, we have a fixed parameter vector $θ=(θ_1,θ_2,θ_3), ∑θ_i =1$
We have the following generative story:

1. Draw $n\sim Poisson(\lambda)$
2. With respect to $n$, we have a $Multinomial(n,\theta)$
3. Call $C$ a set of all vectors $D=(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ that satisfy:   $D \sim Multinomial(n,\theta)$ and $d_1\times d_2 \times d_3 \neq 0  $

The problem then accounts to the calculation of this summation:
$$S=∑_{(n=3)}^∞(\space p(n|\lambda )×∑_{(D∈C)} p(D |n,θ)\space )$$

The authors introduced this formula :
$$S=e^{-\lambda}∏_{i=1}^3(e^{λ×θ_i} -1)$$
I have been working on the formulas to understand how did the authors present the above formula. However, with the modest skill on summation, I haven't made it out yet.
**I would highly appreciate any clue or instruction on how to come up with the above shortened formula(you don't need to perform the transformation explicitly)**

*Please feel free to ask me if you need further clarifications*

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum, which initially appears to be a quadruple sum, extends over all $n\ge 3$, $d_1 \ge 1$, $d_2\ge 1$, and $d_3\ge 1$, where $n=d_1+d_2+d_3$.  Therefore it's really just a triple sum over all integral tuples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ with coordinates extending from $1$ upwards.

Moreover, from the Poisson formula

$$p(n\mid\lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$

and the Multinomial formula

$$p(D\mid n,\theta) = \frac{n!}{d_1!d_2!d_3!} \theta_1^{d_1}\theta_2^{d_2}\theta_3^{d_3}$$

the cancellation of $n!$ in numerator and denominator and the identity $\lambda^n=\lambda^{d_1}\cdots\lambda^{d_3}$ allow us to simplify the product--which is the quantity being summed--as

$$p(n\mid\lambda)\,p(D\mid n,\theta)  = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{d_1}\theta_1^{d_1}}{d_1!} \cdots \frac{\lambda^{d_3}\theta_3^{d_3}}{d_3!} = e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda\theta_1)^{d_1}}{d_1!}\cdots \frac{(\lambda\theta_3)^{d_3}}{d_3!}.$$

Consequently, applying the series expansion $$e^x - 1 = \sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{x^d}{d!}$$ to the cases $x=\lambda \theta_i$, we may write

$$\eqalign{
S &= \sum_{d_1=1,d_2=1,d_3=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda\theta_1)^{d_1}}{d_1!}\cdots \frac{(\lambda\theta_3)^{d_3}}{d_3!}\\&=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{d_1=1}^\infty\frac{(\lambda\theta_1)^{d_1}}{d_1!}\cdots\sum_{d_3=1}^\infty\frac{(\lambda\theta_3)^{d_3}}{d_3!}\\&=e^{-\lambda}\left(e^{\lambda\theta_1}-1\right)\cdots\left(e^{\lambda\theta_3}-1\right)\\&= e^{-\lambda}\prod_{i=1}^3 \left(e^{\lambda\theta_i}-1\right).
}$$